# Quick Email Access

Tags: safari, mail.app, email, gmail

What is this 'Quick Email Access' app and do I need it? I just got a new laptop and it has this app. I've used gmail for years and never had any problems without this app.
Whether this is related or not, I don't know: in my search bar in Safari is "search.hquickemailaccess.biz"....  I chose as my search engine, Google, but, this won't go away.
How do I get rid of these, or do I need them?

Comment: New Macs should never come with **any** 3rd party apps pre-installed... so I'd be intrigued to know how it got there at all unless you installed it yourself.

Comment: If that app is on your laptop then it's not a new Mac.  Where did you buy it and do you still have the receipt to return it?  I wouldn't trust any computer that came with software not installed by the manufacturer.

Comment: please See for unknown extensions that might be there in Safari

Comment: I would tend to think spyware/adware that the previous owner or store you bought it from installed on your Mac. Take it back or reformat it and reinstall macOS.

Comment: New Mac from Apple Store, but, two days later I was bought an iPhone from Verizon Store and I now believe that is how "Quick Email Access" got here, but, I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Get an antivirus suite.